# How to duplicate the digits in a string with that many occurences of the character following java

Tags: java

The title is what I'm trying to do.For example if the string is 3s than the output will be ssss.
What I've done:

```
 public class StringCode1 {
       public static String f(String str) {
       String s = new String();
       for (int i=0; i<str.length(); i++){
          char c = str.charAt(i);
          if(Character.isDigit(c)){
            //int rez = s.rep
             //and here I don't know how to duplicate the digit
          }
         }
        } 
       }
```

Some ideas?Thank you.

Comment: the logic is not clear , please provide some examples of inputs and the requested result, thanks .

Comment: @JClassic I read the requirement as interpolating the `3` with 's'. Thus 4 s.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `StringBuilder`. Keep the index where you started. Find the first non-digit character, then add that many copies to the `StringBuilder`. Finally, return the `String`. Something like

```
public static String f(String str) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    char[] arr = str.toCharArray();
    int start = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (Character.isDigit(arr[i])) {
            continue;
        }
        int count = Integer.parseInt(str.substring(start, i));
        char ch = arr[i];
        for (int t = 0; t <= count; t++) {
            sb.append(ch);
        }
        start = i + 1;
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Which I tested like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(f("3s"));
}
```

And I got (the requested)

```
ssss
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you only need to support a single digit/character combination:

```
private static Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([\\d]+)(.+)");

public static String f(String str) {
    Matcher m = pattern.matcher(str);
    if (!m.matches()) {
        // Here you have a chance to reject the input in some way
    }
    String ch = m.group(2);
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(ch);
    for (int i = 0, n = Integer.parseInt(m.group(1)); i < n; i++) {
        result.append(ch);
    }
    return result.toString();
}
```